# Monte Carlo with Metropolis algorithm extremely slow in Python

Tags: python, simulation, montecarlo

I'm trying to implement a simple Monte Carlo in Python (to which I'm fairly new). Coming from C I'm probably following the wrongest path since my code is far too slow for what I'm asking: I have a potential hard sphere-like (see `V_pot(r)` in the code) for 60 3d particles and periodic boundary conditions (PBC), so I defined the following functions

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from numpy import inf
#
L, kb, d, eps, DIM = 100, 1, 1, 1, 3
r_c, T = L/2, eps/(.5*kb)
beta = 1/(kb*T)
#
def dist(A, B):
    d = A - B
    d -= L*np.around(d/L)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(d**2))

#
def V_pot(r):
    V = -eps*(d**6/r**6 - d**6/r_c**6)
    if r > r_c:
        V = 0
    elif r < d:
        V = inf

    return V

#
def ener(config):
    V_jk_val, j = 0, N
    #
    while (j > 0):
        j -= 1
        i = 0
        while (i < j):
            V_jk_val += V_pot(dist(config[j,:], config[i,:]))
            i += 1

    #
    return V_jk_val

#
def acc(en_n, en_o):
    d_en = en_n-en_o
    if (d_en <= 0):
        acc_val = 1
    else:
        acc_val = np.exp(-beta*(d_en))

    return acc_val

#
```

then, starting from the configuration (where every line of the array represents the coordinates of a 3D particle)

```
config = np.array([[16.24155657, 57.41672173, 94.39565792],
       [76.38121764, 55.88334066,  5.72255163],
       [38.41393783, 58.09432145,  6.26448054],
       [86.44286438, 61.37100899, 91.97737383],
       [37.7315366 , 44.52697269, 23.86320444],
       [ 0.59231801, 39.20183376, 89.63974115],
       [38.00998141,  3.84363202, 52.74021401],
       [99.53480756, 69.97688928, 21.43528924],
       [49.62030291, 93.60889503, 15.73723259],
       [54.49195524,  0.6431965 , 25.37401196],
       [33.82527814, 25.37776021, 67.4320553 ],
       [64.61952893, 46.8407798 ,  4.93960443],
       [60.47322732, 16.48140136, 33.26481306],
       [19.71667792, 46.56999616, 35.61044526],
       [ 5.33252557,  4.44393836, 60.55759256],
       [44.95897856,  7.81728046, 10.26000715],
       [86.5548395 , 49.74079452,  4.80480133],
       [52.47965686, 42.831448  , 22.03890639],
       [ 2.88752006, 59.84605062, 22.75760029],
       [ 9.49231045, 42.08653603, 40.63380097],
       [13.90093641, 74.40377984, 32.62917915],
       [97.44839233, 90.47695772, 91.60794836],
       [51.29501624, 27.03796277, 57.09525454],
       [10.30180295, 21.977336  , 69.54173272],
       [59.61327648, 14.29582325, 11.70942289],
       [89.52722796, 26.87758644, 76.34934637],
       [82.03736088, 78.5665713 , 23.23587395],
       [79.77571695, 66.140968  , 53.6784269 ],
       [82.86070472, 40.82189833, 51.48739072],
       [99.05647523, 98.63386809,  6.33888993],
       [31.02997123, 66.99709163, 95.88332332],
       [97.71654767, 59.24793618,  5.20183793],
       [ 6.79964473, 45.01258652, 48.69477807],
       [93.34977049, 55.20537774, 82.35693526],
       [17.35577815, 20.45936211, 29.27981422],
       [55.51942207, 52.22875901,  3.6616131 ],
       [61.45612224, 36.50170405, 62.89796773],
       [23.55822368,  7.09069623, 37.38274914],
       [39.57082799, 58.95457592, 48.0304924 ],
       [93.94997617, 64.34383203, 77.63346308],
       [17.47989107, 90.01113402, 81.00648645],
       [86.79068539, 66.35768515, 56.64402907],
       [98.71924121, 38.33749023, 73.4715132 ],
       [ 0.42356139, 78.32172925, 15.19883322],
       [77.75572529,  2.60088767, 56.4683935 ],
       [49.76486142,  3.01800153, 93.48019286],
       [42.54483899,  4.27174457,  4.38942325],
       [66.75777178, 41.1220603 , 19.64484167],
       [19.69520773, 41.09230171,  2.51986091],
       [73.20493772, 73.16590392, 99.19174281],
       [94.16756184, 72.77653334, 10.32128552],
       [29.95281655, 27.58596604, 85.12791195],
       [ 2.44803886, 32.82333962, 41.6654683 ],
       [23.9665915 , 49.94906612, 37.42701059],
       [30.40282934, 39.63854309, 47.16572743],
       [56.04809276, 30.19705527, 29.15729635],
       [ 2.50566522, 70.37965564, 16.78016719],
       [28.39713572,  4.04948368, 27.72615789],
       [26.11873563, 41.49557167, 14.38703697],
       [81.91731981, 12.10514972, 12.03083427]])
```

I make the 5000 time steps of the simulation with the following code

```
N = 60
TIME_MC = 5000
DELTA_LIST = [d]
#d/6, d/3, d, 2*d, 3*d 
np.random.seed(19680801)
en_mc_delta = np.zeros((TIME_MC, len(DELTA_LIST)))
start = timeit.default_timer()
config_tmp = config
#
for iD, Delta in enumerate(DELTA_LIST):
    t=0

    while (t < TIME_MC):
        for k in range(N):
            RND = np.random.rand()
            config_tmp[k,:] = config[k,:] + Delta*(np.random.random_sample((1,3))-.5)
            en_o, en_n = ener(config), ener(config_tmp)
            ACC = acc(en_n, en_o)
            if (RND < ACC):
                config[k,:] = config_tmp[k,:]
                en_o = en_n


        en_mc_delta[t][iD] = en_o
        t += 1


stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop-start)
```

following the rule of the Metropolis algorithm for the acceptance of the proposed move extracted with `config_tmp[k,:] = config[k,:] + Delta*(np.random.random_sample((1,3))-.5)`.

I made some attempts to check where the code get stuck and I found that the function `ener` (also because of the function `dist`) is extremely slow: it takes something like `~0.02s` to calculate the energy of a configuration, which means something around `~6000s` to run the complete simulation (60 particles, 5000 proposed moves).

The outer for it's just to calculate the results for different values of `Delta`.

Running this code with `TIME_MC=60` can make you an idea of how much slow is this code (`~218s`) which takes just some seconds if implemented in C. I read some other question about how to speed up Python codes but I can't understand how to do it here.

## EDIT:

I'm now almost sure that the problem is in the function `dist`, since just to calculate PBC distance between two 3D vectors it takes around `~0.0012s` which gives crazy long times when you calculate it 5000*60 times.

Comment: I haven't groked the whole program, but it seems ```dist``` is only ever called on vectors, yet uses generic matrix operations to essentially calculate the euclidean distance (plus some rounding). Have you tried implementing that as a less-generic, more-specific version for what you want to do? Maybe there is already a highly optimized method available for it as it's a common distance function. Other than that the rounding seems inefficient and possibly superfluous, though it depends.

Comment: @OP, I agree with your edit. Can you confirm what objects (`A` and `B`) are passed in through dist? As @EtienneOtt points out, it looks like be calculating the euclidean distance, so maybe we can change the dist function.

Comment: @EtienneOtt I haven't tried, is there a specific syntax for np.arrays functions? Jerry M. I just need np.arrays to be passed to dist, and yes it's just the euclidean distance plus the rounding due to the PBC.

Comment: I'm not sure if 1-dim arrays (vectors) are handled much differently than matrices in numpy. What I meant is that you can "unroll" the functions to the specific operations you need to calculate the distance. The reason why this can potentially improve performance is that a.) you have fewer overhead to ensure matrix dimensions match, clever tricks that only matter for big N, etc. and b.) you can potentially re-arrange the operations for faster calculation and pre-compute some things. E.g. dividing by scalar is usually faster as multiplication by the inverse scalar. I'll post more later.

Comment: Nice, but just to be clear: ""unroll" the functions to the specific operations" means merely writing directly the code without defining the function?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The clue is that functions don't always like to be handled like mathematical operations (for rearranging, canceling, etc.) so improving the calculation usually becomes easier when broken down to individual operations. But also be careful that floating point arithmetic has nasty pitfalls when doing formula cancelations, inversions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a partial answer continued from comments on the original question.

Here's an example of how "unrolling" numpy's function can improve performance when replaced with a more direct calculation of the distance. Note that this was not verified to be equivalent, especially concerning the rounding. The principle still applies, I think.

```py
import random
import time
import numpy as np

L = 100
inv_L = 0.01
vec_length = 10
repetitions = 100000

def dist_np(A, B):
    d = A - B
    d -= L*np.around(d/L)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(d**2))

def dist_direct(A, B):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        diff = (A[0,i] - B[0,i])
        diff -= L * int(diff * inv_L)
        sum += diff * diff
    return np.sqrt(sum)

vec1 = np.zeros((1,vec_length))
vec2 = np.zeros((1,vec_length))

for i in range(0, vec_length):
    vec1[0,i] = random.random()
    vec2[0,i] = random.random()

print("with numpy method:")
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, repetitions):
    dist_np(vec1, vec2)
print("done in {}".format(time.time() - start))

print("with direct method:")
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, repetitions):
    dist_direct(vec1, vec2)
print("done in {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

Output:

```
with numpy method:
done in 6.332799911499023
with direct method:
done in 1.0938000679016113
```

Play around with the average vector length and the repetitions to see where the sweet spot is. I expect the performance gain is not constant when varying these meta-parameters.